# dynamically give pdf path in pdf.js using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf.js

I've developed a small application in php and mysql, where i'm uploading pdf and moving file to UPLOADS folder and storing path in database.

But in viewing after passing path i'm not able to open pdf on browser.
I've uploaded PDF.JS files in my folder aswel.
Below are my testing urls.

http://www.farukhzama.com/fileupload/index.php

http://www.farukhzama.com/fileupload/view.php

Comment: Crosspost https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7933

Answer (score 0):

Your link is :
http://www.farukhzama.com/fileupload/viewer.html?file=uploads/47920-ombudsman-acknowledgement.pdf at view.php file, which is wrong path to get the pdf file.

Give it right path like this => http://www.farukhzama.com/fileupload/uploads/47920-ombudsman-acknowledgement.pdf
Thanks!